# What are my options for pre-paid SIM cards in Buenos Aires, Argentina?

Tags: cellphones, argentina, buenos-aires, pre-pay

I have three devices:

1. iPhone 5 - nanosim, 4G/LTE
2. MiFi - microsim, 4G/LTE
3. iPhone 4S - microsim, 3G

Which providers in Buenos Aires / Argentina have the best prepaid options for these devices? They don't all need to be from the same provider, but that would make purchasing simplest. I need voice, sms, & data on both iPhones and only data on the MiFi (I can live without the MiFi).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 major carriers in Argentina

Claro, Movistar and Personal

- All three offer prepaid cards you can buy on literally hundred of shops around the city (I am not sure were in Buenos Aires you are going, but if you are traveling to Capital Federal, then you will find shops on the streets, on every shopping mall, and big movie complex. There are some impromptu *sidewalk shops* across big avenues, but the discount you will get with them is not worth it).
- The first thing they will sell you is the *chip*(SIM) which is around $30 ($6 USD).
- Once the number is activated, which is instantly, you can charge your new number on any kiosk around the city. You will see signs with a legend like ("Cargamos Personal/Movistar/Claro"). You will be asked for your number and the amount you want to charge and they will send you the credit instantly.You should receive an SMS confirmation with your new credit. You will have to pay with cash on most of the Kiosks. If you want to use a CC go to a branded store or use the online option at the official website for the carrier.

  [Personal Stores](http://www.personal.com.ar/centrosdeatencion/) / [Movistar Stores](http://www.movistar.com.ar/atencion-al-cliente/cecs-movistar/) / [Claro Stores](http://www.claro.com.ar/wps/portal/car/pc/personas/ayuda/centros-de-atencion)
- Make sure to ask the seller for current "deals". Quite often you will find 2x1 on all your credit (You will get $200 for $100) or unlimited SMS for 1 day, or free 500 SMS.
- All three companies currently offer unlimited 3G for $1 peso a day ($0.20USD).
- For Claro and Movistar (and probably Personal) you have free calls for clients of the same company.
- Prices will vary A LOT depending on your plan. Make sure to ask the person selling you the chip which one is more convenient.
- In Capital Federal is quite easy to find free WiFi. Almost every coffe shop, fast food chain or shopping mall will have open and free spots.

Finally if you are visiting Argentina with United States Dollars or Euros remember there is a huge differente between the official price and the paralel valuation.

$1USD can either be $4.90 pesos or $7.50 pesos depending which market you trade.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info, really helpful. Can you elaborate / point me to a link that explains more about the "official price and the paralel valuation."

Comment: Sure, here is a graph showing the current USD/ARS http://www.google.com/finance?q=USDARS&ei=BYIBUejREYbYkwPifw (going up fast) and here you will find what is called "Dolar Blue" in Argentina http://www.dolarblue.net/. Here is a Wikipedia article explaining the Dolar Blue http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%B3lar_blue is in spanish but you can use Google to translate it. I would suggest you open another question if interested because I can't fit a full explanation in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, created a new [question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12967/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-ars-using-usd).

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's next to impossible to find MicroSIM / NanoSIM cards. I wasn't able to find any shops that have the machine for cutting the cards, so I ended up going to a papelería and buying a box cutter to shave it down to size myself. It's pretty easy to do if you have a SIM already to use as a template.

Comment: For things that you don't easily find in the streets make sure to use MercadoLibre http://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/microsim its argentinean ebay

Comment: They are no longer instantly activated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Prepaid Data Wikia on Argentina](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Argentina):

> Claro:
>
> 1 hour $3 2 hrs $5 4 hrs $7 6 hrs $10
>
> 1 day $20 2 days $30 5 days $50 10 days $100
>
> to activate send an SMS to: 454 with: 1h, 2h, etc
>
> Movistar:
>
> 5 hrs $9
>
> 1 day $10 (upto 1GB)
>
> 7 days $59
>
> to activate send an SMS to: 226 with: DIA
>
> Personal:
>
> 1 day $10 (up to 1GB)
>
> Special offer: 1 day $1 (first 10MB download at regular speed, next
>   data at 64Kbps)

Comment: Oh wow, there's a prepaiddata wikia! +1!!!!

Comment: @MarkMayo I know right! Best discovery ever I've made in recent months. Incredibly useful.

Comment: This information is out of date, I ended up going for a Movistar SIM and data packs are automatically charged at $1/day for unlimited use. They don't offer prepaid data packs that you have to subscribe to anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I used Movistar all over the country. You can buy a sim (pronounced seem) in a Movistar office for 30 peso. Once its activated you have to then go buy credit from a shop or kiosk, I would just go into a shop and say "recharge" and point at my phone, they will then ask for your number,best to have it written down to show them, and the amount of credit you want. It currently cost 2.45 peso per 15mb.

I had to set a APN up called 'internet' with a username and password also of 'internet' to get the internet connection working.