# Exchanging USD for ARS tips

Tags: exchange, argentina, buenos-aires

So I'm heading to Argentina next week, and whilst there's [heaps of advice on SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12967/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-ars-using-usd) about taking USD cash and exchanging at the arbolitos for the [blue dollar](http://dolarblue.net/), I was wondering if anyone has any tips/locations/things to look out for when I do this? I've heard you can be ripped off, so as a single female non-Spanish speaking traveler I'm just wanting to be cautious. Especially looking for advice from someone who has traveled to Buenos Aires recently please.

Comment: To avoid being ripped off, the unofficial exchange rate can be found on http://www.dolarblue.net/ If you know beforehand what the blue rate is, then there are less changes of being scammed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue rate is the street rate. You will be changing dollars on the street. So, yes, there is a risk involved.

That said, it's a fairly small risk. Though technically perhaps not legal, street changers are so common and the exchanges are so public, you're likely not to run into problems.

In Buenos Aires, go to the city's main shopping street, Florida. Every few meters, money changers will be announcing their service.

That said, if you're not comfortable with changing money on the street, don't do it. Or do it in small installments. Or ask your hostel/hotel reception whether they can help you. In the latter case, you might not get the best rate available, but you're less likely to run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use [azimo.com](http://www.azimo.com), this has been a life saver for me. Allows you to send peso to several locations in Argentina for pick up. Its safe and cheap, and most importantly its at the blue exchange rate!

Comment: Looks very similar to transferwise.com   - What are the locations for money pickup?