# How to get rid of Argentinian Peso before leaving the country?

Tags: money, exchange, argentina

Does anyone have any good suggestions of how to get rid of Argentine peso before leaving the country?

I have read peso can be hard to exchange back or if it can it can only be done at the poor official rate.

Is there anything I can do to retain the value?

Comment: spend your money?

Comment: Umm... the official rate would be VERY GOOD if you want to change Pesos to Dollars. Which is why you won't get it anywhere, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the simplest is to find your nearest hostel in town, and go find the backpackers.  Someone is bound to have just arrived and wanting the local currency (ARS), and may have USD or EUR to give you in exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Find the nearest friendly little tree and sell your pesos on the blue market:

[What is the best way to get ARS using USD?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12967/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-ars-using-usd)

Answer (score 3):

You can also exchange it at the airport. To do so you must have a receipt for when you first exchanged whatever currency you had for ARS. This is so that you can prove how you got ARS in the first place.