# Is it worthwhile to rent a phone in Buenos Aires?

Tags: cellphones, rental, buenos-aires

I'm taking a quick trip to Buenos Aires and while I know I can [buy a SIM card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12948/what-are-my-options-for-pre-paid-sim-cards-in-buenos-aires-argentina) for my phone, what I am curious about is the options of renting a cheap voice only phone while I am there.

Various websites offer such services in Buenos Aires and promise to deliver to your hotel (thus saving the time/hassle of hunting down a SIM card), but none mention prices or give me much confidence in their quality.

So do these sites deliver on their promises? And how does the cost stack up against a pre-paid SIM?

Answer (score 1):

[Baires Apartments](http://www.bairesapartments.com/cell-phones.html) (a temporary rental and real state) offers phone rentals and, as you mention, they send it and pick it up for free (to/from the hotel, or to/from the airport).

The Cell phones are free of charge. You just pay the calls.

The rates are of course more expensive than a normal cellphone you can buy and top-up, but still not terrible:

Locals:                 **AR$ 1,50** | 
National:           **AR$ 1,99** | 
Argentina - Mercosur    AR$ 3,19 | 
Argentina - U.S.    AR$ 3,49 | 
Argentina - Europe: AR$ 4,59 | 
Argentina - México-Venezuela-Israel AR$ 3.79 | 
Incoming Calls          **AR$ 1.00**

Cellular rental: AR$ No Charge | 
Insurance: AR$ 19.00*

So local calls would be $1,50 pesos or, at today's change rate, **0.19 US** Dollars.

Another company is For [Rent Argentina](http://www.4rentargentina.com/buenos-aires-cell-phone-rental.html), phones are also free but the price per minute doubles.

Comment: Thanks for the rate information.  But do you have any ideas on the quality of service? ie do they deliver on time?  I'm trying to estimate the level of hassle of SIM vs rental.

Comment: @PeterM I haven't used them myself, but if they deliver to the airport then they might have an office there. Some rentals I saw online look a bit shifty, but if they depend on a property rental (an actual company) then it's a safer bet.

Comment: I saw that Rent Argentina also bills you for a minimum of 10 minutes per day.  I am looking into these companies plus another one I know of.